# What form of life was brought to earth by aliens?

Tags: science-based, evolution, aliens

For this question, we'll assume that **life on Earth was brought by aliens**. They didn't do anything specific to our planet: they saw that it was compatible with the lifeform they wanted to seed, so they just got down and put life on Earth.

What did this *form of life* look like?

I want to assume that they dropped the **most evolved lifeform possible**, without denying any of today's science. Fossils and other proofs of the earliest stages of life on Earth must be taken into account in your question. But see that in this question, everything that we have no scientific proof was physically on earth at some point needn't have been.

Also these aliens dropped **one and only one form of life**, many specimens if need be. If the alternative is fun, you can include in your response a scenario where they dropped more than one lifeform, but this is not the main purpose of this question.

Bonus: *how long ago was this?*

Comment: So, this is the very first lifeform on our planet? A single-celled organism? Not very evolved...

Comment: For clarification, let me check: (1) they drop one lifeform at time X; (2) the evolutionary fossil record looks as it does today; (3) they drop the most evolved form they can; (4) they do nothing else of significance. So, (A) what lifeform, and (B) when was the drop. Right?

Comment: @theonlygusti well we don't have actual proof that the single-cell common ancestor lived on our planet. It is just the most probable guess. Remaining consistent with the evidence we have, could aliens have dropped a more evolved lifeform?

Comment: The problem with the question, if my comment is accurate, is that most of the formulation presumes the aliens did **not** initiate life on Earth. They made an insertion that eventuated in our evolutionary history. Perhaps revise the opening boldface?

Comment: @Sheraff Yes we do: how do you explain fossils (billions of years old; the Earth is just 4 billion years old) of amoeba being discovered? No multicellular organism would devolve into a single-celled one, at least, not probably.

Comment: @theonlygusti then I guess that could be the answer.

Comment: @CAgrippa, your first comment is exact. You could also add (0) they are the ones who initiated life on earth. I don't get your second comment.

Comment: @theonlygusti Also, this question started when I stumbled upon [this PNAS article](http://www.pnas.org/content/111/23/8380) that seems to question Earth’s oldest trace fossil

Comment: note that you not only have to consider fossil record, but also the fact that there's oxygen on earth, which was [created by very early lifeforms] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geological_history_of_oxygen). So I guess, if life has come from alies, it would have to be very early and rough forms.

Comment: just for inspiration - I think the Prometheus movie http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1446714/ was about this at the start, not sure now if it described the life origin or mankind origin

Comment: It has to be four point something billion years ago, and non-oxygen-requiring, but beyond that there are far too many possibilities.

Comment: @Gilles Could you explain why there are too many possibilities?

Comment: We know very little about how life appeared. We know that the oxygen-rich atmosphere was formed by oxygen-producing life (anaerobic bacteria), but beyond that point in time we know extremely little about this anaerobic bacteria. I suppose if “anaerobic bacteria” is enough detail for you, then this question is answerable.

Comment: can we assume that organic cells evolved on earth by themselves, separate from the lifeforms that the aliens drooped?

Comment: @dsollen No, the question assumes that Life was brought on earth by aliens, not just some life. Sorry if that is unclear.

Comment: @Sheraff the problem is that if you set that as a requirement your limited to single cell organisms as what aliens brought, which is very boring.  If you allow the presumption that basic life evolved on it's own, but all the advanced multi-celular organisms are from alien's you can allow more advanced creatures being brought by the aliens without invalidating science.  Of course even then 'more advanced' is pretty basic, but at least it's not single celled.

Comment: I really don't understand the 'too broad' close votes. It seems from all the comments and answers that the solution to my question is something along the lines of "a type of anaerobic bacteria", which is already more evolved than just proto-life and less evolved than oxygen breathing life.

Comment: I don't think the question -- now that I understand it -- is too broad. It's very specific. But it looks as though it may not be answerable.

Comment: @CAgrippa Well it wouldn't take half a novel to answer it like some other questions, but and answer still could be provided. I'd be satisfied with a short but well justified answer. Even if it is broad because it's impossible to give a very narrow answer.

Answer (score 3):

What you describe is pretty futile.

If they drop one form of life it cannot be very advanced - as it will have nothing to feed on. No oxygen to breathe, etc.

A single celled photosynthesizing bacteria or algae is probably your best bet...

You want one and only one form of life - but the most evolved. Those factors heavily counter each other - all higher life forms are dependent on a vast ecosystem of other life forms. Plants producing oxygen and food, symbiotic bacteria, etc. To be able to exist in isolation as the only life form on the planet then your organism has to be very simple.

Comment: The oldest (known) form of life on Earth didn't breathe oxygen — they breathed *out* oxygen, creating the oxygen-rich atmosphere we know today.

Comment: I don't understand why this is futile. Would you care explaining my "best bet"?

Comment: @Sheraff Added more explanation.

Comment: @Gilles Yes, that's my point.

Comment: Why would anaerobic organisms have to be “not very advanced”? For all we know, there could be very rich forms of anaerobic life, that died out when the atmosphere was poisoned by O₂.

Comment: I disagree that it's contradictory. I said the most evolved *possible*. If it's not possible for it to be very evolved then fine.

Comment: @Sheraff Changed the wording. My point still stands. We have no advanced organisms that are capable of existing in isolation.

Comment: @Gilles It's not just about the anaerobic - it's about the lack of anything else. All advanced lifeforms are sustained by a complex web of interactions with thousands or millions of other different lifeforms.

Answer (score 3):

Since presumptive traces of biological activity can be found in the *oldest* (in an absolute sense) rocks, life seems to have formed as soon as the earth cooled enough, and instantly on a geological timescale.

Perhaps batches of what we woukd term *proto-life* were dropped as soon as Earth cooled to that point, first providing concentrated environments in isolated places, and then seeding the ocean with what could be used as food for the rapidly emerging life forms.

A more subtle idea would be to provide a bit of luck, making sure any needed conditions are met if they are lacking naturally. For example, provide a load of bio-active "fixed" nitrogen — one of the remaining weak links in our understanding of how it might have happened.

Maybe they could curate the infalling material, still massive though not so much as to boil the oceans and remelt the lot, making sure the rate *doesn't* get too high on occasion, and the right elements are introduced and the wrong ones kept away, with optimal timing for the emerging life's needs.